# Split array by months

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a json where there are data only for the current year, the date is in ISODATE format, how could I, angular 1 separate the json objects by month, for example, throw the data to another json, corresponding to the month defined on the date of the variable.

I did the following:

```
.then(function(resp) {
vm.acoesAno = resp.data
angular.forEach(vm.acoesAno, function(value, key){
    angular.forEach(vm.acoesAno, function(value, key){
        const date = new Date(value.data)
        const mes = date.getMonth()
        if (mes == 0){
            vm.jan = vm.acoesAno[key]
        } else if (mes == 1){
            vm.fev = vm.acoesAno[key]
        } else if (mes == 2){
            vm.mar = vm.acoesAno[key]
        } else if (mes == 3){
            vm.abr = vm.acoesAno[key]
        } else if (mes == 4){
            vm.mai = vm.acoesAno[key]
        } else if (mes == 5){
            vm.jun = vm.acoesAno[key]
        } else if (mes == 6){
            vm.jul = vm.acoesAno[key]
        } else if (mes == 7){
            vm.ago = vm.acoesAno[key]
        } else if (mes == 8){
            vm.set = vm.acoesAno[key]
        } else if (mes == 9){
            vm.out = vm.acoesAno[key]
        } else if (mes == 10){
            vm.nov = vm.acoesAno[key]
        } else if (mes == 11){
            vm.dez = vm.acoesAno[key]
        }
    })  
})  

console.log("mes de maio: ", vm.mai)}
```

There are two objects in the json vm.acoesAno that are registered with the month of May, but in the variable outside the forEach I get only 1 object, the variable inside the forEach stores the two objects.

**JSON DATA vm.acoesAno:**

```
{
    data : "2018-05-06T03:00:00.000Z",
    longitude : "-52.018375",
    latitude : "-27.226520",
    dataCadastro : "2018-05-22T02:57:01.443Z"
}
```

But there are several objects with different dates in that json.

**@vol7ron**

[return from `console.log(grouped[4])`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG21B.png)

Comment: show your json data...

Comment: I edited the question, it's in bold.

Comment: The phrase `throw the data to another json` is grammatically incorrect or incomplete.  As it reads, there is only one notation; *another* doesn't exist.

Comment: `vm.acoesAno` is an array of objects?

Comment: Can you explain why `angular.forEach(vm.acoesAno, function(value, key){` is repeated?

Comment: This is niether a valid json not javascript unless `ISODate` is already defined function `"data" : ISODate("2018-05-06T03:00:00.000Z"),`

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz yes.

Comment: @vol7ron, sorry for my English. I need to filter the array data and separate by month, to later demonstrate them in a chart.

Comment: @Fred do the keys have to be called the month abbreviations?  Why not just stick into an object?

Comment: @vol7ron 
I need to separate into 12 objects, to match the 12 months that will make up the X axis of my chart.

Comment: @Fred, you should make your example data available in the post, not as an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` and regex to match specific month to filter data

```js
// if you want to make it efficient, you can do something

  .then(function(resp) {
    const data = resp.data;
    vm.jan = [];
    vm.fev = [];
    // initialize all arrays to empty array
    vm.acoesAno = data;
    data.forEach(item => {
       if (/(.*)-01-(.*)/.test(item.data)){
          vm.jan.push(item);
       } else if (/(.*)-02-(.*)/.test(item.data)){
         vm.fev.push(item);
       } else if (/(.*)-03-(.*)/.test(item.data)){
          vm.mar.push(item);
       }
      // and so on 
    });

// 2nd method

.then(function(resp) {
    const data = resp.data;
    vm.acoesAno = data;
    vm.jan = data.filter(item => /(.*)-01-(.*)/.test(item.data);
    vm.fev = data.filter(item => /(.*)-02-(.*)/.test(item.data);
    vm.mar = data.filter(item => /(.*)-03-(.*)/.test(item.data);
    vm.abr = data.filter(item => /(.*)-04-(.*)/.test(item.data);
    // and so on for all other months

});
```

Comment: That's much better than iterating over the full array 12 times.  Something to keep in mind, for the December dates (last condition) it means the code would need to evaluate the 11 prior if/else conditions before it was recognized; for november, 10 other conditions would first be evaluated; etc.  Even though they are condition expressions, the efficiency can be improved.

Comment: Tks @ZohaibIjaz! I tested the first method, it Works.

Comment: @Fred, as stated, just be careful.. each condition is an expensive regex evaluation.  This isn't the most efficient code.  You'd do better to discover why the Date/months is not getting the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with Angular anymore, but:

- you should be able to pass the object to the iterator function
- you probably don't need to use the month names as keys, just use their integers
- I'm not sure why two loops were used in this case — wouldn't 1 be sufficient?
- you only have one value because you are using an assignment (`vm.mai = vm.acoesAno[key]`) and not adding to a collection or array, which means you're overwriting on each iteration

```js
.then(function(resp) {
  vm.acoesAno = resp.data
  let grouped = {}
  angular.forEach(vm.acoesAno, function(value, key, obj) {
    const date = new Date(value.data)
    const mes = date.getMonth()
    if (typeof grouped[+mes] == 'undefined')
      grouped[+mes]=[]

    grouped[+mes].push(obj);
  })

  console.log("mes de maio: ", grouped[4])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tested again, I realized now that I'm not getting the expected result. I'm not getting the data for the correct month.

Comment: @fred I could have a typo but could you show what you’re getting or provide a more complete (working) example?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I entered the return at the end of my question. Excuse me

Comment: @Fred nothing above has given reason as to why it wouldn't work.  It would help you to debug what is not working.  Without a working example, no one can help you debug it either.